# How to wrap text (inside relative position div) around absolute position div?

Tags: css, css-position, word-wrap

I am trying to find a solution to the following:

```css
<style>#about {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #D7D8A2;
  border: 0.1em dotted #7A7A7A;
  position: absolute;
  left: -9px;
  top: 105px;
  z-index: 15;
}

#about-ct {
  width: 95%;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 0.1em dotted #7A7A7A;
  position: relative;
  top: -35px;
  z-index: 12;
}

</style>
```

```html
<section id="section">

  <div id="about">About</div>

  <div id="about-ct">Lorem ipsum...</p></div>
</section>
```

This will produce something like this:

[image: Image 1 - Problematic view]

I would like to achieve the following without (if possible) `<br><p style="text-indent:6em;">`

[image: Image 2 - Target view]

So far I wasn't able to figure this out,

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The absolute-positioned element is removed from the document flow, which prevents it from influencing the position of any other elements (including their text).

Comment: Have you tried using `float: left` instead of `position: absolute`?

Comment: Yes, I did `float: left` will produce the text-wrapp, however `<div id="about">` will change position and no longer overflow. I guess other option would be to use transparent image and float it left in the `<div id="about-ct"> to compensate for the size of absolute element.

Answer (score 0):

```css
<style>
  #about {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #D7D8A2;
  border: 0.1em dotted #7A7A7A;
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: #db4344;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 15;
}
#about{
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: #db4344;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 15;
}
#about-ct {
  width: 95%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 10px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 0.1em dotted #7A7A7A;

  top: -35px;
  z-index: 12;
  text-indent: 55px;
}

</style>
```

```html
<section id="section">

  <div id="about">About</div>

  <div id="about-ct">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam porttitor vitae ligula interdum auctor. Donec commodo purus ultrices turpis aliquet, quis sodales nisi euismod. Nunc libero metus, lobortis quis mi sit amet, placerat volutpat enim. Cras libero arcu, aliquam quis rhoncus id, aliquet nec nunc. Pellentesque vel ligula in magna feugiat gravida. Morbi aliquam, diam et fermentum iaculis, mauris risus tristique elit, sit amet ullamcorper diam mi non odio. Nulla facilisi. Cras malesuada justo felis, vitae laoreet justo facilisis nec. Fusce sit amet facilisis ex, sed laoreet nibh. Nulla sit amet justo nisi. Cras eu dui blandit, aliquam velit eget, blandit lacus. Etiam non turpis ut tellus aliquet sodales eu sagittis urna. Nullam et pretium lorem..</p></div>
</section>
```